# I can't figure out why can't pass my variables in main

Tags: c++

I try to pass variables to my employee class but I can't see to figure out why it isn't working. I was following along with a tutorial explaining how it works but did cover how to do with already declared variables. So what do take variables initialized in main and pass them employee so I can use function raise to calculate raise later in the code. Im writing this text to padd the word count so I can post it. How much padding does it what.

```
class Employee
{
private:
        string name;
        int yearjoined;
        double monthlySalary;
    
public:

    Employee()
    {
        name = " ";
        yearjoined = 0;
        monthlySalary = 0;
    }

    void raise(string workerName, int yearJoin, double salary);

    Employee(string workerName, int yearJoin, double salary)
    {
        int yearsworked;
        name = workerName;
        yearjoined = yearJoin;
        monthlySalary = salary;

        cout << name;
        cout << yearjoined;
        cout << monthlySalary;
        /*raise(monthlySalary);*/


    }
    
    void raise(double salary)
        {

        }

};








int main()
{
    
    string userName;
    int userStart;
    double userSalary;


    cout << "What is you name?";
    cin >> userName;
    cout << "What year did you join the company?";
    cin >> userStart;
    cout << "What is you monthly salary?";
    cin >> userSalary;
    Employee worker(string userName, int userStart, double userSalary);
    worker(userName, userStart, userSalary);

}
```

Comment: _"How much padding does it what."_  It doesn't want padding.  Nobody wants padding.

Comment: when you create the employee object, just use `Employee worker(userName, userStart, userSalary)` This is unecessary: `Employee worker(string userName, int userStart, double userSalary); worker(userName, userStart, userSalary);`

Comment: you're essentially redeclaring variables in the same scope if you do this.

Comment: `Employee worker(string userName, int userStart, double userSalary);` looks to the compiler like a function declaration.

Comment: Learning C++ by tutorials can be really rough. A lot of the information you'll find in internet tutorials is substandard-to-harmful and will slow down your learning. Buying a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to use as a guide costs money, but the time you save should quickly pay itself off.

Answer (score 2):

You made one error trying to pass the variables, which made the compiler think you wanted something completely different.

This line:

> ```
> Employee worker(string userName, int userStart, double userSalary);
> ```

The compiler understands it as deceleration of a function named `worker` that receives 3 arguments and returns an object of class `Employee`.

This is because you wrote types and variable names in the brackets.

Next, this line:

> ```
> worker(userName, userStart, userSalary);
> ```

The compiler now thinks you want to call the `worker` function you declared in the previous line (because you wrote nothing before `worker`), but when it comes the time to link your code (put it together with all functions it needs), there is no function `worker` defined anywhere, so you get an error.

What you need to do, is combine those 2 line in one like this:

```
Employee worker(userName, userStart, userSalary);
```

Now you are telling the compiler to create a variable of type `Employee` and initialize it with 3 values using the constructor you wrote.